# Information from the template after redirection, Django - Python

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a simple view that allows me to add comments in my Django template.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    review_form = ReviewForm(data=request.POST)
    if review_form.is_valid():
        rating = review_form.cleaned_data['rating']
        comment = review_form.cleaned_data['comment']
        user_name = review_form.cleaned_data['user_name']
        order_code = review_form.cleaned_data['order_code']
        review = Review()
        review.masseurs = masseur
        review.rating = rating
        review.comment = comment
        review.user_name = user_name
        review.order_code = order_code
        review.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        review.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:masseur_detail', args=(masseur.id,)))

else:
    review_form = ReviewForm()
```

After adding the comment, the user is redirected to the basic page. I would like to display a thank you and information here, the comment has been added. 
How can I create an element in my view that will check if a new comment has just been added (after redirection). I tried to use something like 'new_comment = review_form.save (commit = False)' but it does not work properly (or I am doing something wrong). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to use the Django messages framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/)

Comment: Django messages framework is your best choice for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

**in views.py**

```
 from django.contrib import messages
if request.method == 'POST':
    review_form = ReviewForm(data=request.POST)
    if review_form.is_valid():
        rating = review_form.cleaned_data['rating']
        comment = review_form.cleaned_data['comment']
        user_name = review_form.cleaned_data['user_name']
        order_code = review_form.cleaned_data['order_code']
        review = Review()
        review.masseurs = masseur
        review.rating = rating
        review.comment = comment
        review.user_name = user_name
        review.order_code = order_code
        review.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        review.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Added successfully!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:masseur_detail', args=(masseur.id,)))

else:
    review_form = ReviewForm()
```

**in template add this line**

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
        {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}Important: {% endif %}
        {{ message }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Hope it help