# Success message after parsing keywords in print output in view.py

Tags: python, html, django

First of all am very new to coding in general, but have managed to setup an automation website for network devices.

Basically am trying to parse an output generated by "print (output)" in view.py for some keywords and if that keyword exist display a success message in my template

view.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    hostname = request.POST.get ('host')
    username = request.POST.get ('username')
    password = request.POST.get ('password')
    srcrouting = request.POST.get ('srcrouting')
    rtsubnet = request.POST.get ('rtsubnet')
    destrouting = request.POST.get ('destrouting')

  remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
  remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  remote_conn_pre.connect(hostname=hostname, port=22, username=username,
                        password=password,
                        look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

  remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()

  remote_conn.send("\n")
  remote_conn.send("en\n")

  remote_conn.send(str(password)+ "\n")

  remote_conn.send("conf t\n")

  remote_conn.send("ip route" + " " + srcrouting + " " + rtsubnet + " " + destrouting + "\n")

  remote_conn.send("end\n")

  remote_conn.send("sh run | s" + " " + srcrouting + "\n")
  time.sleep(1)
  route = remote_conn.recv(65535)
  print (route)
  context = {'route': route}
```

I want to parse output of the "print (route)" and if it includes something, display a success message.

Thanks,

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648802/information-from-the-template-after-redirection-django-python/54649267#54649267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/)

```
if "something" in route:
    // logic here
    messages.success(request, 'Show something')
```

and in template

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line with the if command just checks if the variable route contains anything, if so it executes the print command. The print command prints the success message and the  contents of "route" to the screen. On the long-run you might actually want to check what the exact content of route is.

```
if route:
    print("Success! Content of variable route: " + str(route))
```